# select max rows where joined tables used max row difference other

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a tree tables table_1, table_2 and table_3, its structures its

table_1

[image]

table_2

[image]

table_3

[image]

In table_1 I have a unit_id and it is general, I want to select data in all tables, for example unit_id = 5 used in table_2 and table_3 and buildings rows is six, parcel rows is two, I want to select six rows building_id, building_area and beside two rows parcel_id and parcel_area, for unit_id = 6 conversely 4 rows parcels and two rows buildings, and one row buildings when unit_id = 7 and one row parcel when unit_id = 8

```
select result example 


unit_id      building_id    building_area    parcel_id     parcel_area
   5            2                20             15             20
   5            3                10            null           null
   5            4                30            null           null
   5            5                15             16             10
   5            7                25            null           null
   5            8                15            null           null
   6           null             null            21             30 
   6           null             null            22             50
   6            9                18             23             80
   6            10               20             24             70
   7            30               10            null           null  
   8           null             null            27             52
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @jarlh Oracle only

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to left join `table_2` and `table_3` to `table_1`.

```
SELECT t1.unit_id,
       t2.building_id,
       t2.area building_area,
       t3.parcel_id,
       t3.area parcel_area
       FROM table_1 t1
            LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
                      ON t2.unit_id = t1.unit_id
            LEFT JOIN table_3 t3
                      ON t3.unit_id = t1.unit_id;
```

Comment: so not true, left join multiply rows

Answer (score 0):

You do want a left join between all three tables, but by looking at your sample data it seems like you need the relationship between tables 2 and 3 to include the area.

That would be :

```
SELECT 
    t1.unit_id,
    t2.building_id,
    t2.area AS building_area,
    t3.parcel_id,
    t3.area AS parcel_area
FROM 
    table_1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2
        ON  t2.unit_id = t1.unit_id
    LEFT JOIN table_3 AS t3
        ON  t3.unit_id = t1.unit_id
        AND t3.area = t2.area
```